# Training with duplicates in dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data

I have a dataset of images for classification purposes. The dataset is very large and most of the images are duplicates of each other. So essentially, the same image occurs multiple times. Moreover, the dataset is unbalanced.
I understand the motivation of cleaning the dataset of duplicates. But it is extensive and very time consuming to do so.
Is there a way to train a net on this dataset, and not overfit the model?
Could enforcing harsher regularization, dropouts, penalize the losses still produce a usable model?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a possible solution to part of it; deduping doesn't have to be extensive if the duplicates are exact copies. If there is no pixel difference in the duplicates, a potential solution is you could generate a hash (like MD5) of each image and pull only images that have a unique hash into the dataset

Comment: Generating a hash for images is not robust to slight changes in pixel values, say minor lighting changes which aren't visible to the eye but the pixel value differs.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Jon.H in comments, instead of training your model on a dataset with duplicates, you could use image hashing to detect and remove them from the dataset. Although the cryptographic hashing (like MD5 and SHA1) will suffice to find *exact* duplicates, according to your comment you also would like to get rid of similar images, not just exact duplicates (Do you really want to do this? Having a bigger dataset is usually better for training, and keeping similar images with small variations, e.g. in color, is not necessarily a bad thing -- see "data augmentation").

> Generating a hash for images is not robust to slight changes in pixel
>   values, say minor lighting changes which aren't visible to the eye but
>   the pixel value differs. - Ronica Jethwa

One solution to this is to use [perceptual hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing) which is quite robust to minor differences in color, rotation, aspect ratio of images etc. In particular I would suggest you to try the pHash algorithm based on Discrete Cosine Transform as described in [Looks-Like-It](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html). There is a python library that implements it, called `imagehash`. Here's how to use it:

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash

# Compute the perception-hash values (64 bit) for two images
phash_1 = imagehash.phash(Image.open('image_1'))  # e.g. d58e11ce51ee15aa 
phash_2 = imagehash.phash(Image.open('image_2'))  # e.g. d58e01ae519e559e

# Compare the images using the Hamming distance of their perception hashes
dist = phash_1 - phash_2
```

Then it's up to you to choose the similarity threshold for the Hamming distance.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates don't imply over-fitting; they give that image more weight in the training.  Yes, you can train on the data set; the results will be valid.  For instance, if you have the same quantity of duplicates (say, 10 of everything). then you'll get the same results as if you had just one -- or almost: the shuffling order can slightly affect the balance of training, since a single image can now appear multiple times near the start of epoch 1.

The various counter-measures you list are good tools against over-fitting, but your main danger is merely what you have anyway: the potential of a small set of unique examples.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my cent to this old question.

During training the problem arises only if you have a high chance of having many duplicates in a single batch.
Let's say you choose a batch size of 64; since you will randomly sample the images to compose the batch it could be that on average you have only 2 duplicates. This really depends on how many times (on average) an image is duplicated in proportion to the total number of images.

Anyway the problem is alleviated by using (online) data augmentation which introduces some differences, even between identical images.

The biggest problem is on the test set because the accuracy estimation will be biased towards the images with more duplicates, so I would embrace the effort and deduplicate the test (and validation) sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same images in the validation set as in the train set, but different in the test set, the validation will give a better (accuracy) score than test. In this case, it will be like overfitting. Duplicates occur naturally everywhere, therefore it must be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Train with duplicate data. Use the representation vector i.e output of last convolution. If you using pretrained CNN model use the final out of that.  Apply knn or clustering on the representation vectors and identify duplicates. Remove duplicates and retain your model.